# Can someone help me set up tensorflow & neural-style-tf please?

Tags: python, cuda

I'm pulling my hair out trying to set up tensorflow and neural-style-tf from github

https://github.com/cysmith/neural-style-tf

keep getting errors after following guides:

https://youtu.be/Rmjp1yFi9Ok?t=2109

and at this point number 6: I am getting errors. ..

```
'Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 10 2018, 20:35:02) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('hello!')
>>> sess = tf.session()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'session'
>>>'
```

I noticed the python version says (AMD64) on Win32, is this the possible error? (i am intel)

any ideas?

many thanks for any help at all   - i'm a competent end user but really in the dark with coding.  I am using this for experimental moving image

edit* just wanted to add - i dont want to really touch any coding - i'm a visual artist trying to come up with new forms of moving art. All i want to do is get the neural-style code running on my PC so I can make some images. i managed before with the first public release of deepdream but that took me two days of work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add line breaks to your code. Add a line break after your import statement and your code should look like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('hello!')
sess = tf.Session()
```

Try re-running the code and see what you get. If you still get an error try re-installing tensorflow with the following command. Also, the way your are using constant doesn't really make sense if this is the first line of code in your project. If this is your first time writing code, I recommended getting familiar with the basics first.

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```

I am also not sure what you're setting a hello variable. Tensorflow is a pretty advanced library for a beginning programmer. You might want to explore some easier projects for your own sanity. Going straight into tensorflow is like learning calculus before learning to add.

I also noticed that you have a lowercase session, change the line 
    sess = tf.session()

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu  I get 'invalid syntax' . this is in anaconda prompt.

Comment: I just noticed in your code you have a lowercase session change the line look at my updated answer and run the code again.

Comment: i tried that, it seems to work !   many thanks.  now I guess on to the next part

Comment: ok, the last part is to install keras apparently?  I installed git and tried via the git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git   command and got this error:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                           I apologise for the unclean writing i'm not used to forums where enter doesnt make a line break!

Comment: run the following command in the terminal `pip3 install Keras` , to get to this on windows type in cmd in the search bar and run it through there

Comment: I just got this running on my Macbook. I'm in the data science field but had never seen this before, it's a really cool library. It was a pain in the ass to get running however, If you need anything else let me know. I will be happy to help, what type of computer are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Hayes.  I am on windows 10 x64.  `py -m pip install keras` worked for me. Something to do with the python paths not being there & i guess I only have plain pip not version 3.

Comment: ok, so a test.py program worked, apart from a warning to update my 'dense' call.    Unfortunately i then tried the 'neural_style.py' and got error 'import cv2 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: run the same command that worked for you on windows then, probably `py -m pip install opencv-python` to install cv2